# Can I say 'fall far of [sth]' by analogy of 'fall short of [sth]'?

Tags: phrase-request

Can I say 'fall far of [sth]' by analogy with 'fall short of [sth]'? If not, what expression can be used instead to mean that the result of some actions was far from what was planned/expected?

Comment: The idiom "a far cry from" what was planned/expected might work.  However, "fall far of..." is not used, perhaps "fall far from..." is a better construction if this is used.

Comment: @Katherine I need an idiomatic verbal phrase